# Printf-like function in F# computation expression

Tags: f#, monads, computation-expression

I'm trying to write a code in F# that allows logging to custom source and using generating random number sing swappable implementations.

Instead of passing logging function/random generator to every function in the application, I'm trying to pass these functions as a context of computation expression.

I've noticed it is very similar requirement to state monad implementations, so I've tried to write something similar.

I have proof of concept working, and generating numbers is working very good, but I cannot make it to work nicely with printf style parameters for my logging function:

```
module Test

type Simulator = { random : int * int -> int; logger : string -> unit }

module Simulator =
    let create = let random = new System.Random() in 
                     { 
                     random = fun (min, max) -> random.Next(min, max)
                     logger = fun str -> (printfn "%s" str |> ignore) 
                     }

type Simulation<'T> = Simulation of (Simulator -> 'T)

module Simulation =
    /// Runs a simulation given a simulator
    let inline run state simulation = let (Simulation(play)) = simulation in play state
    /// Returns a random number
    let random min max = Simulation (fun simulator -> simulator.random (min, max))
    /// Writes to simulation log
    let log = Simulation (fun simulation -> Printf.ksprintf simulation.logger)


type SimulationBuilder() =
    member this.Bind (x, f) = let (Simulation(simulation)) = x in Simulation (fun simulator -> f (simulation simulator))
    member this.Return (x) = x

let simulate = new SimulationBuilder()

let simpleSimulation =
    simulate
        {
        //very nice, working
        let! x = Simulation.random 2 12
        //this is working, but verbose
        let! logger = Simulation.log 
        do logger "Value: %d" x
        //I want to write 
        //do! Simulation.log "Value: %d" x
        // or something similar
        return x;
        }

Simulation.run Simulator.create simpleSimulation |> ignore
```

Can someone help me? I'm pretty new to writing custom computation expressions.

**EDIT**

Note that log function could have signature

```
let log str = Simulation (fun simulation -> simulation.logger str)
```

and it would be easy to call:

```
simulate
   {
   ...
   do! Simulation.log "Hello world!"
   ...
   }
```

but here I am losing ability to pass format parameters without using sprintf

**EDIT**

There is an error in bind implementation, should be:

```
member this.Bind (x, f) = let (Simulation(simulation)) = x in Simulation (fun simulator -> Simulation.run simulator (f (simulation simulator)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that your `log` function returns the printing function wrapped in `Simulation`, so that you have to use an extra `let!` to unwrap it before you can use it.

But nothing prevents you from wrapping the *function's result* in `Simulation` rather than the function itself:

```
let log = Printf.ksprintf (fun str -> Simulation (fun simulation -> simulation.logger str))
```

This will let your code compile:

```
do! Simulation.log "Value: %d" x
```

Because now the expression `Simulation.log "Value: %d"` returns a function `int -> Simulation<unit>` rather than `Simulation<int -> unit>` as it did before.

---

However, this will also monomorphise the `log` function: the compiler will see that it's used with a single `int` parameter, and will fix its type to accepting `int`s, and then if you try something different:

```
do! Simulation.log "Value: %s" "foo"
```

it will not compile again, complaining that it was expecting an `int`, but given a `string`.

To fix this new problem, you'll have to help the compiler out a bit by providing an explicit generic type annotation and specifying exactly how it should be translated to `ksprintf`:

```
let log (format: Printf.StringFormat<'T, _>) = 
  Printf.ksprintf (fun str -> Simulation (fun simulation -> simulation.logger str)) format
```

Here, `'T` represents the string of parameters, like `int ->` or `string -> bool ->` or whatever else your format string specifies.

With this, any format will compile:

```
do! Simulation.log "Value: %d" x
do! Simulation.log "Value: %s" "foo"
do! Simulation.log "I have %d apples which are %s" 42 "rotten"
```